# JButton in array wont update text

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton

I've created an array of buttons, added them to my frame and (inefficiently) created action listeners for each of them which open a JOptionPane to take an input and add it to a String array, yet the text on the array button does not update after the popup is closed, while a button not part of an array updates its text fine.

The string array grabs the data from the JOptionPane fine, it just wont update the button's caption.

In my full program I'm writing ar_str_vals to a .xml file, and it can properly save and load the array, and surprisingly the array buttons properly set their text but only at the beginning of my program.

```
package wtf;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Wtf extends JFrame{
        JButton[] ar_btn_vals = new JButton[2];
        String[] ar_str_vals = new String[2];
        public Wtf(){
        super("Title");
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        constructor();
        actionlisteners();
        }

public void constructor(){
    for (int x = 0;x<=1;x++){
        ar_btn_vals[x] = new JButton();
        ar_btn_vals[x].setText(ar_str_vals[x]);
        ar_btn_vals[x].setBounds(5,(100 * x)+20, 100,40);
        ar_btn_vals[x].setVisible(true);
        add(ar_btn_vals[x]);
        System.out.println(ar_str_vals[x]);
    }

}

public void actionlisteners(){
    for (int x=0;x<=1;x++){
        switch (x){
        case 0:
                ar_btn_vals[0].addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                        ar_btn_vals0ActionPerformed(evt);
                    }
                });
            break;
            case 1:
                ar_btn_vals[1].addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                        ar_btn_vals1ActionPerformed(evt);
                    }
                });
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void ar_btn_vals0ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFrame frm_val0change = new JFrame();
    String newval = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frm_val0change, "Enter new Button 1 Value");
    ar_str_vals[0] = newval;  
    constructor();
}

private void ar_btn_vals1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFrame frm_val1change = new JFrame();
    String newval = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frm_val1change, "Enter new Button 2 Value");
    ar_str_vals[1] = newval;  
    constructor();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Wtf frame = new Wtf();
}
    }
```

I'm aware that this isn't as efficient as it could be, but I've got limited time to finish this and I have absolutely no idea why this isn't working properly.

This is also my first time asking a question, so please have mercy if I've formatted anything wrong.

Comment: Rather then calling constructor again, update the buttons text with setText in the ActionListener

Comment: @MadProgrammer That fixed my problem. I guess that's what I get for being lazy and just calling constructor over and over again. Any idea why calling constructor properly updates buttons that don't belong to an array, but can't update buttons inside the array?

Comment: Well, it's a combination of things, you're just adding new buttons over and over again (and since you've done away with layout manager) to the same position, so it comes down to a z-ordering position, and from what remover, the components are painted in reverse order, but if they weren't, it's still a bad idea to call constructor again

Comment: @MadProgrammer OH that makes sense... I had a similar issue with  creating action listeners inside my constructor earlier but I figured that issue out, I'm not sure why I couldn't notice the same problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MadProgrammer said, all I had to do was update the button text in my action listener instead of calling the constructor again.